# Angular Access list Properties

Tags: angular12

In my`I have cities with`id`and`name`and`counteyid`and countries with`id`and`name`how to iterate this`response.value`to get a list having`cityid,name,countryid`?

[image]

Comment: could you add more details, some code example etc, the images sometimes could not be reachable

Comment: response.value = cities[
    {
        "id": "1",
         "name": "cityname";
         "countryId": "countryId"
        "countries": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "countryname",
        },
        ]
    }
]
so, i want a list that have cityId,name,Countryname from response.value

Comment: if my answer is solve your problem , please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Also, don't add code in the comments, edit the post instead and include the code in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use map function I guess, here some example with your code. I extend your list like that and result shown below

```js
       const value = [
            {
                id: "1",
                name: "cityname",
                countryId: "countryId",
                countries: [{ id: 1, name: "countryname" }],
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                name: "cityname-2",
                countryId: "countryId-2",
                countries: [{ id: 2, name: "countryname-2" }],
            },
            {
                id: "3",
                name: "cityname-3",
                countryId: "countryId-3",
                countries: [{ id: 3, name: "countryname-3" }],
            },
        ];

        // you can check your list result
        console.log(
            value.map((m) => ({
                cityId: m.id,
                cityName: m.name,
                countryId: m.countryId,
            }))
        );
```